MS Excel - Count rows where multiple columns meet different criteria
I am trying to automatically count samples that pass or fail based on multiple criteria. Countifs works beautifully for the pass condition where all criteria must be passed, but I'm struggling with the fail condition. A fail is defined when any single criteria fails.
I'm trying to make a summary table of the data that looks like this:

With data that looks like this:

To count passing samples, I use: =COUNTIFS(B7:B11,"Pass",C7:C11,"Pass")
What formula should I use to count fails? =COUNTIFS(B7:B11,"Fail",C7:C11,"Fail") returns "1" for the sample that failed both criteria.

This works great for my example, but I'm struggling to scale it for my actual case, where the criteria are all different. For example, criteria 1 might be "1.000 +/- 0.001" and criteria 2 might be "5.000 +/- 0.500".

Subtract from Total not suitable?

@Blackcat That works. I can do =counta(B7:C11)-COUNTIFS(B7:B11,"Pass",C7:C11,"Pass") if I want the formula to fit in one cell.

Count Rows Where All Cells Meet a Condition
Step By Step
=LET(data,B2:C6,yes,"Pass",
    yd,IF(data=yes,1,),
    rc,ROWS(yd),
    cc,COLUMNS(yd),
    y,BYROW(yd,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r))),
    o,IF(y=cc,1,),
    p,SUM(o),
    r,VSTACK(p,rc-p,rc),
    r)


Replace the last r with any other variable to see what it holds.

The r inside BYROW is a different variable.

If you have access to the ETA lambdas, you could use:
y,BYROW(yd,SUM),




Short
=LET(data,B2:C6,yes,"Pass",
    y,IF(data=yes,1,),
    r,ROWS(y),
    p,SUM(IF(BYROW(y,SUM)=COLUMNS(y),1,)),
    VSTACK(p,r-p,r))


IMO you have oversimplified your actual case. I'm looking forward to the question about it.

